# center single column in Masonry layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using the jquery/css masonry layout for a menu layout. Some menu pages only have one column so I need to centre the column, any idea how to do this? Currently using the following javascript:

```
<script>
var msnry;

function triggerMasonry() {
  // don't proceed if masonry has not been initialized
  if ( !msnry ) {
    return;
  }
  msnry.layout();
}
// initialize masonry on document ready
docReady( function() {
  var container = document.querySelector('.menu-columns');
  msnry = new Masonry( container, {
    gutter: 10
  });
});
// trigger masonry when fonts have loaded
Typekit.load({
  active: triggerMasonry,
  inactive: triggerMasonry
});
</script>
```

Comment: could you set up a fiddle including the html and css? My first thoughts are to create a wrapper around your menu and just center the whole bunch. Then it doesn't really matter how many columns you have

Answer (score 0):

You can add empty or hidden bricks to replace the wanted column.